# Ionic: How to let my click event go through

Tags: javascript, click, ionic-framework

I created a link and programmatically click it:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = "mymap.png";
a.href = canvasdata;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

The above code block successfully fires a click normally, however it would be blocked by the ionic tap event handling system because of this function in ionic.bundle.js :

```
function tapClickGateKeeper(e) {
    ...
    // do not allow through any click events that were not created by ionic.tap
    if ((ionic.scroll.isScrolling && ionic.tap.containsOrIsTextInput(e.target)) ||
(!e.isIonicTap && !ionic.tap.requiresNativeClick(e.target))) {
//console.log('clickPrevent', e.target.tagName);
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (!ionic.tap.isLabelWithTextInput(e.target)) {
         // labels clicks from native should not preventDefault othersize keyboard will not show on input focus
          e.preventDefault();
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

This function does not let through click event without isIonicTap set to be true. So my own click event created in Javascript is blocked as well here.

How can I let my click event go through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My case is to set attribute data-tap-disabled="true" on the element.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but still want to add my answer.
In my case I have tried to save CSV file form ionic App.
So this code worked:

```
a['type'] = 'submit' ;

document.body.appendChild(link);
var e1 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e1.initEvent('mousedown', true, true);
a.dispatchEvent(e1);

var e2 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e2.initEvent('click', true, true);
a.dispatchEvent(e2);

document.body.removeChild(link);
```

This code based on [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/programmatically-trigger-click-event-of-button-on-android/94239) thread from iOnic forum.